# Canceling an accepted dialog in Qt (aka user error checking)

Tags: c++, qt, modal-dialog, error-checking

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I want to be able to error check what the user inputted in a modal dialog when they hit 'OK', and allow them to go back and fix it without closing the dialog.

Is there something I can set within the 'OK' button's slot callback that will tell the dialog not to close?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use done method which you could know return value is rejected or not.

for example:

```
void ExDialog::done(int res)
{
  if (res == QDialog::Accepted)
  {
    // check if it is ok or not
    if(not)
    {
      ShowErrPopUp();
      return;
    }
  }

  QDialog::done(res);
}

// when ok button is clicked
void ExDialog::action_ok_bt_clicked()
{
  this->accept();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer to what I asked. I'm also going to check out QValidator as an alternative.

Comment: I fixed my code. Checking status in done method is more appropriate to work I think.